# No se muestra una lista en C

Tags: c

Tengo una estructura stUser que cargo a un archivo. Desde ese archivo, mediante las llamadas a las siguientes funciones desde el main, se cargan los registros a una lista:

```
nodoListaUsers * listaUsers = inicListaUser();
stUser nuevo = cargarUser();

printf("\n\n ARCHIVO:");
mostrarArchivoUsers(ARCHI_USERS);

archiToLista(ARCHI_USERS, listaUsers);

printf("\n\n LISTA:");
mostrarListaUsers(listaUsers);
```

Todas funcionan correctamente, hasta el momento en que llega a `mostrarListaUsers`:

```
    void mostrarListaUsers(nodoListaUsers * lista)
{
    nodoListaUsers * seg = lista;

    while(seg) /// no entra al while
    {
        mostrarUser(seg->user);
        seg = seg->sig;
    }
}
```

He hecho printfs en todas las funciones y llegué a la conclusión de que no entra al while (porque seg es null), pero no sé cómo resolverlo, siempre hice esta función así y corrió como debía.

También puse printfs por toda la función de `agregarUserEnOrden` (la que, luego de creados los nodos, los agrega a una lista por orden de ID de usuario) y `archiToLista` (la que pasa los registros a una lista). **Ambas se ejecutan completas.**

```
nodoListaUsers * agregarUserEnOrden (nodoListaUsers * lista, nodoListaUsers * nuevo) // criterio: ID
{
    if(lista==NULL)
    {
        lista = nuevo;
    }
    else
    {
        if(nuevo->user.id < lista->user.id)
        {
            lista = agregarUserPpio(lista, nuevo);
        }
        else
        {
            nodoListaUsers * ante = lista;
            nodoListaUsers * seg = lista->sig;

            while(seg && (nuevo->user.id > lista->user.id))
            {
                ante = seg;
                seg = seg->sig;
            }
            nuevo->sig = seg;
            ante->sig = nuevo;
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

---

```
nodoListaUsers * archiToLista(char archivo[], nodoListaUsers * lista)
{
    stUser usu;
    FILE * fp = fopen(archivo, "rb");

    if(fp)
    {
        while(fread(&usu, sizeof(stUser), 1, fp) > 0)
        {
            nodoListaUsers * aux = crearNodoUser(usu);
            lista = agregarUserEnOrden(lista, aux);
        }


        fclose(fp);
    }

    return lista;
}
```

**Esta es la salida:**
[image: Salida del programa]

Answer (score 0):

Estás pasando tus punteros por copia:

```
odoListaUsers * agregarUserEnOrden (nodoListaUsers * lista, nodoListaUsers * nuevo)
```

Esto hace que todo cambio que hagas sobre `lista` dentro de la función, se quede dentro de la función, puedes ver ese efecto en este ejemplo:

```
int diez = 10;
int veinte = 20;

void puntero_pon_10(int *p)
{
    printf("dentro de %s, p es %p &p es %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, p, &p);
    p = &diez;
};

void puntero_puntero_pon_20(int **p)
{
    printf("dentro de %s, p es %p &p es %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, *p, p);
    *p = &veinte;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int *puntero = &i;
    printf("dentro de %s, p es %p &p es %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, puntero, &puntero);
    printf("puntero = %d\n", *puntero);

    puntero_pon_10(puntero);
    printf("puntero = %d\n", *puntero);
    puntero_puntero_pon_20(&puntero);
    printf("puntero = %d\n", *puntero);

    return 0;
}
```

Que produce [la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##rZHBa8IwFMbPzV/xUCpt6Yb1WreLKHipY9SDMAjSRBeYSUhbDxv@7d1LItghOxS8lLzHl@/35Wv1dKyqrhsLWX21jMO8bphQz5@vhAjZABP8G14gm@ZuPHP8clzMcEHOSjDQLW6MolpJmk0jq0p0TH5IoA0Oh2jEuGyMAjQP6xQ08BpCDZPr4UOOUqD07X1Zlju62haLcr0pKEVliqI4RyMETmySnFzusD387Ip/ED/BAI6fuAD@7T6CxZz2QkYOZCeBEuwk8O/3oewtkT@gCG9n6/CnuGd6Y4XMWSQ3Ear@/p2B94N/Wh6ew/CmNdI2dOm6Xw)<sup>1</sup>:

> ```
> dentro de main, p es 0x000000000001 &p es 0x000000000002
> puntero = 0
> dentro de puntero_pon_10, p es 0x000000000001 &p es 0x000000000003
> puntero = 0
> dentro de puntero_puntero_pon_20, p es 0x000000000001 &p es 0x000000000002
> puntero = 20
> ```

Puedes ver que en la función `puntero_pon_10` se cambia el valor del puntero `p` pero ese cambio no se refleja en la variable `puntero` de `main`, esto es porque es una copia de dicho puntero y estás afectando la copia. En cambio en la función `puntero_puntero_pon_20` recibes la dirección de `puntero` y en consecuencia puedes hacer cambios que le afecten. Deberás hacer las mismas correcciones en tu código.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Los valores de los punteros son ficticios.